# What's the most used alternative to React Native?

Tags: javascript, html, programming, framework, css

I am not a native app developer but to broaden my general knowledge I ask:

What's the most used alternative to React Native?

What will you recommend to try as such?

Comment: Welcome. I think that this question will be closed as off-topic, but will try to give some advice. First, what are you using it for? If you mean apps for Anroid and Apple iOs, then I highly recommend Flutter / Dart (spend $15 on Undemy for doctors Angela Yu's excellent turorial, which might take you a few weeks to complete). If you have something else in mind, please tell us what. Good luck :-)

Comment: "Most used" is not a good parameter for a software recommendation. Come up with a list of features you want and then add those to the question and it'll be greatly improved.

Comment: On such a broad question the answer will most likely base on use opinion.For example C# developers most likely will prefer Xamarin. Others my prefer Apache Cordova/Ionic or something similar. In my opinion all those platform independent languages have one major drawback and you still need to write more or less platform dependent code...